# SP2013 - Display a column for certain documents in a folder

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

I've been nominated as my company's SharePoint guy and I've been asked to set up a Document Library for the Marketing department to share approved documents with the rest of the business.

I've created a Team Site and then added the Document Library App. Then I've created a couple of parent folders as so:

[image]

You can see that there is a column I have created for "Website Link" which is where we want to fill with a hyperlink to the place where that document is hosted on our public facing website. However we don't want that column in this current place. Ideally, we would want it so that the "Website Link" column only appears on documents which have a link, or at least so that it only appears in the "Public Documents" folder. Basically a column that only appears once it is relevant to where the user is in the library.

Is something like this possible? Ideally I'd prefer a solution which doesn't involve using JavaScript.

The screenshot above shows the document library as is, without the use of an app or web part.

EDIT: Forgot to say that the folders have permissions applied to them. Normal users can view public and internal documents but then only people member of an AD Security group can then see the marketing and restricted folders

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of alternatives which are better methods to accomplish what you are wanting to do.

My 2 cents is to forego a folder structure, but rather create a content type for each of your document types: Internal Documents, Marketing, Public Documents or Restricted Documents.  You can then add the column 'Website link' to only the Public Documents content type.

You could also go the route of creating separate document libraries for each document type.

Comment: I just had a thought of maybe adding the hyperlink as a property on the document? A user could then view the properties of the document and get the URL, without cluttering the main view. Do you know how I would go about adding a property to it? The only other option I can think of is creating a view which shows that column and just giving the user the option to change their view

Comment: You could create a choice field that lets users indicate what type of document it is, then create a view for each choice instead of using folders. Then you could include the link column in only the Public Documents view.

Comment: @ErinL The only issue is this; users only have access to documents that are either public or internal. Then documents that are for marketing or are restricted are locked down by permissions. That's why I've done folders, so I can apply the permissions to those parent folders.

Comment: How many documents have special permissions? If it's close to 500, then you're right, you have to either use folders, or break them into separate libraries as Jason suggested.

Comment: @ErinL At the moment it's not much, but will grow. Almost certainly over 500. The issue I can't seem to find a fix for is that we will have a lot of columns and I don't want them all in the same view because it will be horrible for users to use. The only thing I can think of is using multiple views and giving them the option to change between them.

Comment: It really sounds like there are enough differences that you should be breaking them into separate document libraries. Different columns and different permissions are very good reasons to use more than one library.

Comment: Agree with Erin.  Separate libraries will tackle your need to apply custom permissions as well as address different columns required for different document types.